# Why do I have so many file systems on my ubuntu server and what's the usage of each?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, disk-usage

I issued `df -H` command on my system and saw the following output

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs            95M  3.1M   92M   4% /run
/dev/mmcblk0p2   32G  3.2G   27G  11% /
tmpfs           475M     0  475M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
/dev/mmcblk0p1  265M  156M  110M  59% /boot/firmware
tmpfs            95M  4.1k   95M   1% /run/user/1000
```

What I want to understand here is after installing ubuntu on my system, which had only one hard drive with no partitions.

1. How do I have so many file systems here?
2. What's the usage of each of them?
3. How can I view the type of each file system installed by ubuntu here?

Comment: 1. Do you meant the 4 `tmpfs`, 2. / is root, /boot/firmware is part of the boot, the tmpfs are various uses. 3. check `mount` for type of fs ... likely to be type `tmpfs` for the `tmpfs` entries ... maybe ext4 for / and vfat for the boot partition

Comment: yes and /dev/mmcblk0p1, as I understand /dev/mmcblk0p2 is the main root filesystem to which all other fs attaches to

Comment: `/dev/mmcblk0p1` is likely to be part of the boot process, perhaps something to do with EFI

Comment: Downvoter, please comment what's wrong with the question, secondly my question is why do I have so many tmpfs and along with that what's the usage of new fs  "/dev/mmcblk0p1"  that is created

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Comment: You can view the discs (block devices), their partitions and their file system types using `lsblk` and then `lsblk -f`. That will make the `df` output more understandable. Wikipedia has an article on `tmpfs`.

Comment: Note the `tmpfs` do not appear on the block device reports, because they are not stored on any device. They are faked up as file systems in RAM *only* (they may be swapped out like normal process pages, though).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First the "real" filesystems:

- `mmcblk0p2` is your root filesystem, and it's most likely using some Unix-style filesystem, like ext4, XFS or similar.
- Since `mmcblk0p1` is mounted to `/boot/firmware`, it apparently has something to do with the boot process; perhaps your system architecture (RasPi or some other ARM I guess?) requires a partition with a specific filesystem type (like FAT32?) to boot from, to update firmware, or something like that?

Then the `tmpfs`-based ones, roughly in the order they were introduced:

(`tmpfs` is a RAM-based filesystem whose contents are lost whenever the system is rebooted. Its memory usage grows and shrinks automatically as required: the size specified is actually a maximum size limit. If unused, a `tmpfs` filesystem takes an absolutely tiny amount of memory.)

- `/run/lock` was earlier `/var/lock`, and since it contains lock files and similar files that become useless if the system is rebooted anyway, very soon after first systems based on solid-state memory were developed, even before the 2.6.x kernel series, someone had an idea to place this directory to a RAM-disk to save write cycles on solid-state media. It remains a separate filesystem to allow sizing it independently, as it may need to be accessible to (some) users in some cases, and since lock files are *tiny*, this can be restricted to a very small maximum size.
- Before a simple, space-efficient general-purpose RAM-disk filesystem `tmpfs` was developed, there was a more restricted version of it known as `shmfs`. It was used to implement a particular style of shared memory access at `/dev/shm`. Now a fully general-purpose `tmpfs` can do the same job and more, but the mount location remains.
- `/run` and `/run/user/1000` seem to be `systemd`-related inventions. Both are general directories for UNIX sockets, PID files (if needed) and everything similar that loses their meaning if the system is rebooted, so a RAM-based `tmpfs` is a natural place for them. The first one is for system services; the second is for user-specific services for the user with UID number 1000. These can have more generous maximum size allocation, but stricter permissions than `/run/lock`.

---

As mentioned in the comments, you can use `lsblk -f` (or my personal favorite, `lsblk -o +fstype`) to see actual (= non-`tmpfs`) filesystems with their filesystem types listed.

Comment: You can display and organize _everything_ mounted with: `mount | sort -k5 -k3 | column -t`